# HTML in a window

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I want to make a window with HTML that works similar to ones opened by windows. I know the method with actual browsers, but it isn't good enough as I have link and navigation buttons.

This would make my job easier in making softwares with lots of animations

Comment: you mean to say Windows explorer? But why you want to open windows explorer from javascript ?

Comment: because I find making games in html is more easy to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can get is calling [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) with third argument set as: `'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no'`.

This will open a new browser window with only the address bar shown.

There is no way to open a native window out of the browser's scope from JavaScript code other than this. It is a security limitation.

However, the other alternatives include are `Window.alert` or a `Window.prompt`.

Comment: But I saw Game Dev Tycoon who is made that way. There is really no way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a popup box you can use `alert("This is a dialog box!");`, `confirm("Is it ok or not?");` or `prompt("Enter a value and confirm it or not");`.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

If you want to open a native window, that is not possible as it has already been said.